# React Native - changing screen content while animating

Tags: react-native, animation, react-hooks

I have an animated screen using gesture handler, and reanimated libraries. My problem is I am trying to change the screen content while the animations fired. I have made it work, but honestly I am 100% sure this is not the best solution (or it might be, but need some more configurations)

Code:

```
const onStateChangeLogin = event([
  {
    nativeEvent: ({state}) => block([
      cond(eq(state, State.END), set(buttonOpacity, runTiming(new Clock(), 1, 0))), call([], () => handleTapLogin())
    ])
  }
]);
```

In the call function, I am trying to change the content:

```
const handleTapLogin = (e) => {
setContent(<Login />)}
```

This is the Animated.View:

```
<TapGestureHandler onHandlerStateChange={onStateChangeLogin}>
        <Animated.View style={{...styles.button, opacity: buttonOpacity, transform:[{translateY: buttonY}]}}>
          <Text style={{...styles.buttonText, color: colors.white}}>{strings.signin}</Text>
        </Animated.View>
      </TapGestureHandler>
```

And the screen content is located in the bottom of my 'return' method:

```
    ....</Animated.View>
        </TapGestureHandler>
        {content}
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  </Container>
```

So it's working now, but too slow. I think because the call function in the event is async. So what happens now, the content is changing, but sometimes I need to wait like 2-3 secs to see the right screen.

I have already tried to use 'listener' in the event function:

```
const onStateChangeLogin = event([
  {
    nativeEvent: ({state}) => block([
      cond(eq(state, State.END), set(buttonOpacity, runTiming(new Clock(), 1, 0))), call([], () => handleTapLogin())
    ], {
      listener: () => handleTapLogin
    }
  )
  }
]);
```

And I'm also tried to use onGestureEvent and onHandlerStateChange together like:

```
<TapGestureHandler onGestureEvent={onStateChangeLogin} onHandlerStateChange={handleTapLogin}>
        ...
</TapGestureHandler>
```